# How can i retain the value of value even after reload javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my script. When the document is ready i seat

```
$(document).ready(function(){           
    localStorage.searchFlag = false;
    localStorage.search = "";
    alert(localStorage.searchFlag + " search:" + localStorage.search);
});
```

And when i click the submit button i want to change the value of the searchFlag and search

```
<form class="form-search" style="float:right" action="javascript:searchKeyword('search-inbox');" method="POST" id="search-inbox">
  <input type="text" class="input-large search-query" style="height:30px">
  <button type="submit" class="btn search" id="search-inbox">Search</button>
</form>

function searchKeyword(search){      
     var keyword = $(".search-query").val();
     var offset = start - 1;
     localStorage.searchFlag = true;
     localStorage.search = search;
     search = search;        
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo site_url("network_test/searchmessages"); ?>",
        data: {keyword: keyword, search: search, offset: offset},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
    if(search == "search-inbox"){
                $("#message-body").html(data.html);
            } else if(search == "search-sent"){
                $("#message-list").html(data.html);
            }
        }
    });
    alert(localStorage.searchFlag + " search:" + localStorage.search);
}
```

Please help im a newbie in web development

Answer (score 0):

The way you are storing and getting value from the local storage is not correct.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    sessionStorage.setItem('searchFlag ','false');  
    sessionStorage.setItem('search','');
    alert(sessionStorage.getItem('search') + " search:" + sessionStorage.getItem('searchFlag '));
});
```

The [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) property allows you to access a session Storage object. sessionStorage is similar to Window.localStorage, the only difference is while data stored in localStorage has no expiration set, data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends. A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores. Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated, which differs from how session cookies work.

[FIDDLE DEMO 1](https://jsfiddle.net/yj4thbcv/2/)

**OR**

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    localStorage.setItem('searchFlag ','false');  
    localStorage.setItem('search','');
    alert(localStorage.getItem('search') + " search:" + localStorage.getItem('searchFlag '));
});
```

[FIDDLE DEMO 2](https://jsfiddle.net/yj4thbcv/3/)

Comment: sir for example i want to store data to sessionStorage.setItem("keyword", " "); how can i display it to the input? i tried <input value="javascript:sessionStortage.getItem("keyword")">

Comment: <input value="javascript:sessionStortage.getItem('keyword')"> add single quotes

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing like this:

```
localStorage.searchFlag = false;
```

You need to set like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('searchFlag','false');
```

To get them use like this:

```
localStorage.getItem('searchFlag');
```

Here's a good [tutorial](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/) for this.